# vb.net datagridview Event scroll to selected row

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem for days trying to solve and to no avail,I had already posted here before but exclude it to make improvements to the demo. I have a Datagridview "dgvdados" filled with data from the SqlServer database.

I need to use the dgvdados_Scroll event so that when scrolling down or up it selects the line according to its vertical scroll bar value.

I'm using the code:

```
 Private Sub dgvdados_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles dgvdados.Scroll
 
   dgvdados.Rows(e.NewValue).Selected = True
 End Sub
```

However, it selects only the first visible line of the dgvdados, and not according to the value of the vertical scrollbars. In addition, it generates an error "The index was out of range" when moving the horizontal scroll bar.

Vision of what is happening:

[image]

I would like it to work as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve what I want? it seems almost impossible. I appreciate any help that comes

Comment: Might have to use a scroll bar control rather than relying on the ones built into the DVG.  That way you can set the min/max to match the number of records in your data and have direct 1:1 match with the scrollbar value.  As a bonus gets you around the issue with the horizontal scroll

Comment: Hi, @Hursey, Could you post an example answer to help me? really the way I said it can work.